# The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

**Here is the part of the widget the i´m having the problem**

```
DateTime? _selectedDate;

(...)

     Container(
        height: 70,
            child: Row(children: [
              Text(_selectedDate == null
                  ? 'No date chosen!'
                  : DateFormat.yMd(_selectedDate)),
              TextButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Choose date',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                onPressed: _presentDatePicker,
              )
            ]),
          ),
(...)
```

The problem happens when i check if _selectedDate is null, insed the Text widget, just like i´m showing on the image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of DateFormat is a bit different. The first, optional argument is the locale for the DateFormat. DateFormat has a method `format` that takes DateTime as a argument and outputs a formatted String.

```dart
DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate!)
```

If you are using null-safety then you will also need to add `!` at the end of the `_selectedDate`. Dart unfortunetely doesn't promote (from nullable to non-nullable) variables that are properties.